# Possible eigenvalues of a projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the possible eigenvalues of a projection matrix? I know that a projection matrix is any square matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = A$. Thus, we obtain

$$
A^2v = \lambda^2 v \\
Av = \lambda v
$$

for some vector $v \neq 0$. The above imply that $\lambda v = \lambda^2 v$ so $\lambda^2 - \lambda = 0$ so $\lambda = 0, 1$. Does this seem right? For some reason I feel like $-1$ should also be an eigenvalue.

Comment: No, not $-1$. You are done.

Comment: This looks correct.

Comment: You get $-1$ with reflections, which are characterized by $R^2 = I$, so maybe that confused you. For projectors, $0$ and $1$ are O.K.